# Access queries get very slow after about a week, acts like a cache problem

Tags: windows-10, ms-access-2013, labview

We have a strange problem with Access. In our plant we have multiple welders running LabVIEW software. Before each weld the operators scan bar codes on their badges and a tag on the part being welded.

The data from the scans goes to Access databases to verify the operator is authorized to operate the machine and to get information on the part being welded.

After a Windows update a few months ago this process slowed WAY down. One of those database queries could take 20 seconds or more.

We tried using more powerful computers and better network connections, neither helped.
One thing that we did find that helped was running Microsoft’s Office scrub tool, “Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant”. This removes all traces of Office. We then install AccessRuntime_x86 (Access Runtime 2013) so our LabVIEW based software can work with the Access databases.

This restores the systems to normal operation for a week or so, then we need to run it again.
We’ve also found that we can just rerun the Access installer and use the “Repair” option and that helps.

The computers all have i5 processors, 8 or 16GB of RAM, most have SSDs and are running Windows 10 64 Enterprise.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I cannot tell you what it is, but I've got very deep LabVIEW knowledge, and I doubt it is the source of your problems. The only thing it might be: if you see LV's memory usage creeping up over time, check your database refnums and see if you are leaking any. It's a long shot, but it is the only LV-related idea I could brainstorm that would have any effect like what you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One of the things we are looking into is that these LabVIEW programs were compiled on earlier versions of Windows and now we are running 10 Enterprise.  I'm a newby at LabVIEW myself, but we have some guys who are pretty good at it and I'll run this refnum idea past them, from what I've just been reading it's a possibility well worth looking into, although I'm skeptical as I don't see how doing an Office scrub would correct it. But you gave us something else to look at, thanks again!